# Single selection recylcerview item kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

When I click the Recycler View item, I want to change the background color of the clicked item to black and the text color to white.

Also, when I click another item, the previously clicked item changes to the existing color, and I want to change the color of only the clicked item.

Please see my code below and ask for help.
'''
class OrderVintageAdapter(val context:Context, var dataList: ArrayList, var activity:Activity): RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderVintageAdapter.Holder>() {

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int
    ): OrderVintageAdapter.Holder {
        val view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tablayout_item, parent, false)
        return Holder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OrderVintageAdapter.Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(dataList[position], context)
    }

    inner class Holder(itemView:View?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

        fun bind(data:orderVintage, context: Context) {

            itemView.tv_vintage.text = data.vintage
        }
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: can you share the logic code of item click and change color, where exactly you get issue